# Trying to power a MC145010 smoke detector without a battery

Tags: power-supply, battery-operated, smoke-sensor

I'm trying to make a cheap MC145010 based smoke detector "smart" by adding an ESP8266.

Since the ESP8266 needs plenty of power, I have 5V around. I'd ditch the 9V battery that powers it.

I'm converting the 5V that the ESP needs with a MT3608 step-up converter to 9V, the voltage the battery would provide. That's on a pre-manufactured module.

My problem is, the smoke detector works fine on battery, but once I move it to the MT3608 power supply after a (random) while it starts to alert.

Why? How can I fix it?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? ... what is a `smart smoke alarm`? ... please be aware that tampering with a smoke alarm can open you up for legal action should something go wrong

Comment: make sure you draw a minimum load on the 9v to keep it stable, 10ma should suffice, which is easy to accomplish with a resistor and an LED. I would also add a 220u+ cap to the 5v to knock out current spike from wifi, which could cause glitches. I would also add ferrite beads to those 5v and 9v outputs to knock out radio noise which can trigger sensitive sensors like PIR and smoke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely cause is that the supply voltage from a switch mode boost converter is much noisier than virtually noise free supply from a battery.

Perhaps filtering the noise away or just using less noisy supply would work.

It also depends on what kind of 5V power supply you use. Some power supplies have capacitive coupling between mains input and the 5V output, so try another 5V supply.

Comment: I'd tend to agree here. Modern smoke alarms tend to use an NDIR-style detector (the beta decay ones are banned in most places) and they're specifically designed for early detection, so it's certainly possible that they need a very clean voltage rail in order to be able to detect the tiny absorption events from smoke particles, and that PSU noise would cause false alerts. An adjustable linear regulator after the switching regulator is probably the best bet - since it's battery operated it'll certainly be tolerant of running at 8.8V instead of 9V.

Comment: @Polynomial Good idea, rather than accepting a lower supply to the smoke detector IC I see no reason that the 5V could not be raised to say12V and then linear regulated to exactly 9V with low ripple.

Answer (score 2):

@dandavis also deserves credit on this. I already had a 470uF near the ESP. Adding an other 470uF+100nF at the 9V side of converter seems to have solved it.

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing how much 9V noise you have and how close the DC us to your battery and how much CM noise exists in the 5V/Gnd, you can put the battery in and act as a large capacitor.  You may add a series R for safety, measure load current and more importantly attenuate conducted noise.

Comment: Are you suggesting connecting the DC/DC converter's 9 V output to the (possibly primary) 9 V battery?

Comment: Exactly …with a series resistor to act as worst case load and attenuation filter @ocr

Comment: That could well turn the device into a smoke generator.